# "select..into" inside Firebird stored procedure

Tags: sql, select, triggers, firebird

I use Firebird 2.5 64bit edition. I have two tables Master (A) and Detail (B) and I set cascade update and delete for B so if I delete a record in the master any related records in the detail will be deleted as well

I setup an an *After Delete* trigger for table B that executes and passes parameters to a stored procedure

That stored procedure has this SQL:

```
  select STATUS from A
  where A.PK_id = :PK_id
  INTO :var_status;
```

The problem is that I always get `NULL` for the variable `var_status` although I checked it in SQL editor and I get `1` which is the correct value, I also checked (using IBexpert debugger) the passed parameter `:PK_id` and it is also correct!

Why do I get the wrong value stored in this variable.

Comment: Can you post more code, showing how var_status and PK_id are declared and used?

Comment: var_status id declared inside the SP as smallint and PK_ID is the primary key field for table A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probable problem is that you are using `AFTER DELETE` and the record is not there anymore. Here's the order of actions:

- Record gets deleted from A
- Deletion from A cascades to deletion on B
- The `AFTER DELETE` trigger in B gets called.
- From within the trigger, you try to access data not from B, but from A. It's not there anymore.

Remember that the trigger runs inside a transaction. So, probably, when you run the same `SELECT`, you can access the value because you are in another transaction and the original transaction has not been committed yet.

This is not so trivial actually. Here are a few options to solve your issue:

- Check if your business rules can be changed so that you can run that part of code not in a trigger in B, but in A, where the status will be available. After all, there's something you need to do because of A, not B.
- Ultimately, you can remove the `cascade delete` and handle the deletion of B from within the `AFTER DELETE` trigger in A. That way, everything will be in the same block of code.

Comment: you are genius! Exactly what I just discovered few moments before I check your replay (sorry for the poor description) - now as I dont like to write two triggers doing the same thing as users must be able to delete one record from B only- is there a way to modify the transaction so I can read un-commited data (the deleted record from A) ? - or should I create additional table to pass parameters ?

Comment: Although it might be possible, you should not read uncomitted data. Ever. You would solve one problem and create 10 problems. Also, it's not good practice create a table only for parameter passing. Have you considered creating a stored procedure? It can be called from both triggers and you can pass parameters properly.

Comment: ya you are right but for deleting a record from B I will call the SP from Delphi code which I was hoping to do so from the DB - just for knowledge sake how I can read uncommited data inside triggers ?

Comment: I did it I used wildcard Thanks alot Adrian